# Gson deserializer create only super class

Tags: java, json, serialization, gson

I've got a problem with Gson deserializer, it only create super class :/
For example :

```java
public class Fool{}
public class Fool2 extends Fool{}
public class Object
{
/*
This, when recreated by Gson deserializer will create a class of type Fool 
and not Fool2 :/
*/
private Fool fool = new Fool2();
}
```

Is there a way to store the class path of the variable type or something ?
Thanks a lot ;)